# execute/trigger a script depending on #anchor in url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I have a central page `example.com/info/requirements` that contains the requirements to run different applications. By default only the div that shows the requirements for the flagship application is shown, and users can click buttons to switch on/off a different div.

```
<a id="main-app"></a>
<div id="req-container-main" class="invisible">
    [Requirements are listed here]
</div>
<a id="app2"></a>
<div id="req-container-app2" class="invisible">
    [Requirements are listed here]
</div>
<a id="app2"></a>
<div id="req-container-app3" class="invisible">
    [Requirements are listed here]
</div>
<a id="app4"></a>
<div id="req-container-app4" class="invisible">
    [Requirements are listed here]
</div>
```

I have a landing page for each of the apps. They contain a link to the requirements page including an anchor, like this `example.com/info/requirements#app3`

Now I'm looking for a way - using JS/jQuery - that checks for the existence of an #anchor when the page is accessed and can then trigger my `openReqDiv('#app3');` function i have in place.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction when, where and how to check for the anchor and trigger my script? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thing is called routing. Your approach is rather simple, but no worries. Just do:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
switch(hash){
    case '#app2':
        $("#app2").removeClass('invisible');
        break;
}
```

However, eventually you will want to detect changes to the hash. Just use a plugin such as https://github.com/asual/jquery-address. Another option is to use a framework of some kind(angular, ember...)

Comment: Thank you, using window.location.hash seems to be the cleanest solution. Monitoring the hash value for changes is not neccessary, this script just needs to run once each time the page is loaded. I encapsulated you check in `$( document ).ready(function() { });` and it works as intended.

Comment: Oh, perfect. Good luck at your project.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with Javascript using the document.location.href method.

Example:

```
// When the page loads...
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // Check if the hash is in the URL
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('requirements#app3') > -1 ) {
        // Init your function
        openReqDiv('#app3');
    }
});
```

You can modify this function and bind it to a window.load event. So as soon as the user lands on the page your function is executed.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you for your answer. I combined your `document.ready` with @Martin-Gottweis hash (instead of href) and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

You can check the existance of DOM element by this jQuery solution:

```
if($('#anchor').length > 0) {
    openReqDiv('#app3');
}
```